# Neural network based AI in 3d space

Tags: neural-network, coordinates, artificial-intelligence

I've been reading up on neural networks but only just about grasp the basics. I've seen simple examples of distribution and understand those fairly well but I don't see how you would apply neural network based learning to an Artificial Intelligence in 3D space. Say I want the AI to handle moving around the level, dodging projectiles, firing projectiles at opponents, etc.
How would I go about implementing any of these in theory?

Answer (score 0):

One way it seems that you could do this is by having the AI recognize its position as 2 variables (assuming it's bound to a ground mesh) and the position of the projectile as another 2 (or 3, however you decide to do it.) Then you could let the neural net try keeping the AI a certain distance away from the projectiles path.
Shooting seems more complicated but could probably be done using rotation as well as position